# How to compare AT&T-assembly-like sources (e.g. CUDA PTX)?

Tags: cuda, diff, att, ptx, file-comparison

I want to compare two pieces of low-level code, each in its own file. The format is [AT&T-Assembly](https://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Essdavis/50/att-syntax.htm)-style: For me, it's two CUDA PTX files, but this question applies also for the output of `gcc -S` or `clang -S`. For the sake of discussion assume that they're two implementations of the same function.

Now, I can of course `diff` the files textually. The problem is that the register assignments are different. The programs could be completely the same, just with different register names; or a small difference in one line may change the register assignments everywhere (e.g. reduce everything by 1 since an extra register is not used).

I don't mind extra instructions or comments etc. - those are handled just fine by textual diff tools.

My question: What can I do in order to hide those register differences everywhere, for a more "structural" comparison? Should I try some "canonicalization" with a pre-diff'ing parsing script (and if so, which/how)? Can I maybe avail myself of an assembler which takes my code, or a compiler which produces my code, to help me with this?

Comment: Working on GCC/nvptx myself, I sympathize, this is annoying.  However, for me, not yet to such a degree that I'd have done something about it...  ;-P

Comment: @tschwinge: If we at least had a PTX parsing library, we could perhaps feed the AST into some kind of tree-diff'ing tool.

Comment: There are PTX simulators (<http://gpgpu-sim.org/>, <https://accel-sim.github.io/>, <https://sites.gatech.edu/hparch/macsim/>, for example), which maybe could help (assuming they contain suitable PTX parsers, of course) for building such a PTX "canonicalization" tool.  Or, if applicable, do it in the respective compiler back end.

Comment: @tschwinge: It seems gpgpu-sim does indeed have a PTX parser: I see YACC and LEX files in there. However: 1. It's not easy to separate and 2. It is outdated by several yea (e.g. no half-precision types|). But it's a start.